# is there a way to use the char(10) function without separating every value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]I am currently using char (10) to merge columns, from a separate tab called "scripts", into one cell based on a name.
`=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,QUERY(Scripts!$A$3:A,"select B, C, D, E where A ='"&A1&"'")))`

my information shows up in a list. is there a way to combine columns B+C and then D+E.

row 1 is what my data looks like on "scripts" tab.
row 7 is what the data looks like with the above equation.
row 12 is what i would like the equation to do.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, QUERY(
 {Scripts!A:A, Scripts!B:B&" "&Scripts!C:C&CHAR(10)&Scripts!D:D&" "&Scripts!E:E}, 
 "where Col1 is not null"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 {Data!A2:A&"×", CHAR(10)&TEXT(Data!B2:B, "m/d/yy")&
 CHAR(10)&Data!C2:C&", "&Data!D2:D&", "&Data!E2:E, ROW(Data!A2:A)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where not Col1 starts with '×' group by Col3 pivot Col1")
 ,,9^9)), "×")), "^"&CHAR(10), ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! but, sometimes there are multiple entries (ex. date, category, note, tag) for the same name. This returns only the first row of data it sees.

Comment: @EmmaBourdeau can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sI7Yn8kvQo0nQculeIIC9dM_43VzvFF-T7S_TshGIRk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @EmmaBourdeau sheet is private

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sI7Yn8kvQo0nQculeIIC9dM_43VzvFF-T7S_TshGIRk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It should be accessible now.

Comment: I would like to be able to add and delete names in column A. All of the names on the data tab will not necessarily be on the second tab.

Comment: @EmmaBourdeau in that case use this formula from yellow cell in B2 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f14EpSFOXZpdKhq7cR2RwigSBmakedcOf0W5mEX-Qsg/edit#gid=1803422125